# How to use JsonIter to get a specific key value from json , by using any getter method if available ?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonp, jackson2

Am using http://jsoniter.com/  java lib to parse json , it seems with this lib , it only possible to iterate over through the JSON  and did not provide any api to get value for specific key like we have in org.json like below

jsonObject.get("some_key")

so do we have such type of getter methods in http://jsoniter.com/ also , can any one please help me in that .

Answer (score 2):

This is probably already too late, but you can do it like this:

```
    String jsonString = "{'a':1,'b':'text'}".replaceAll("'", "\"");
    Any jsonObject = JsonIterator.deserialize(jsonString);

    long number = jsonObject.get("a").toLong();
    String text = jsonObject.get("b").toString();
```

Comment: could you use this also to get a value at a certain path? I.e. can you also provide a jsonpath in the "get" method?